# Método não altera valores da classe JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou estudando sobre objetos e classes em JavaScript, mas estou tendo um problema o qual não estou conseguindo resolver, criei uma classe para um objeto que seria um simples mario que iria andar pela tela, defini os valores no construtor e as funções básicas para ele inicializar.

O problema é quando executo um método para aumentar o valor de uma propriedade do objeto (no caso a propriedade X), coloquei um console.Log dentro do método para ele me dizer o valor de X e ele simplesmente me retorna no Console que X é NaN (not a number) o que é estranho pois defini ele como valor inicial 100 no construtor, eu coloquei uma função setInterval depois da classe e da instancia para ver se o valor de X aparecia diferente e agora ele aparece, mas o valor está estático(100), parece que no método estou alterando algum x que não é o da classe, tentei verificar, mudar a instancia de let pra var, ver todos os this mas ainda da esse erro.

```
class mario {
            constructor(){
            
                this.x = 100;
                this.marioEl = document.createElement('img');
                this.marioEl.src = 'img/mario.png';
                document.getElementById('quadrado').appendChild(this.marioEl);
            }
            
            movimentar(){
    
                this.x++;
                console.log(this.x);
            }
        }
        
        var mario1 = new mario();
        
        setInterval(mario1.movimentar,100);
        
        setInterval(function verificaX(){
        
            console.log(mario1.x);
            
        },100);
```

Comment: Como código executado pelo `setInterval()` roda em um contexto de execução separado da função que foi chamada o [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#as_an_object_method) da função chamada, é setado como o objeto window ou global. Isso se chama [problema do "this"](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/setInterval#o_problema_do_this) e pode ser contornado usando funções arrow: `setInterval(()=>mario1.movimentar(), 100);` e `setInterval(()=>{console.log(mario1.x);}, 100);`

Comment: PS: Como parece estar fazendo um game veja se essas publicações contribuem https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/451478/137387 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/450496/137387

Answer (score -1):

Diferente de outras linguagens, o this não garante que você vai obter o valor interno da classe, chamado de "problema do this".

Para resolver isso, tem que se fazer usso de arrow functions como demonstrei abaixo

```
class mario {
            constructor(){
            
                this.x = 100; 
            }
            
            movimentar(){
    
                this.x++;
                console.log("movimentar"+this.x);
            }
        }
        
        var mario1 = new mario();
        
        setInterval(()=>{mario1.movimentar()},1000);
```